# WebBrowser Class Inherit Cookies from other browser

Tags: vb.net, cookies, webbrowser-control

Is it possible for the WebBrowser class from VB.NET to use cookies from other browsers, such as Firefox, Chrome, or IE?

Comment: Take a look at this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yk8s7sk.aspx) to understand what inheritance means in VB.NET (more or less the same than in any OO programming language) and, please, correct the title of your question.

Comment: PS: cookies are basically data (= contents of a variable); you can get cookies, the same than the value of another variable (Dim var1 As String = "val1"; Dim var2 As String = var1), nothing to do with inheritance.

Comment: I do not think it is possible as every browser has its own cookie storage format (probably encrypted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just save the cookies as text, using e.g. Fiddler, or F12 in IE, then paste the cookies into strings, and use them in your VB.NET code.